# Как правильно задать вопрос по WordPress?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, вопросы-по-метке

Почему вопросы по WordPress иногда остаются без внимания и обсуждения?

Каким образом сформулировать вопрос по WordPress, чтобы с большей вероятностью получить на него полезный ответ?

Comment: Помню, мы обсуждали этот вопрос пару месяцев назад. Рад, что вы написали ответ. Держите обещанные плюсы.

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к вопросу.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Если вопрос недостаточно четко сформулирован, не содержит ключевой информации, то зачастую участники сообщества предпочитают не тратить время на выяснение деталей, а просто игнорируют вопрос.

**Сделайте вопрос точным**

Вопрос должен быть кратким, точным, но содержащим детали, позволяющие вычленить проблему и дать квалифицированный ответ. Практически всегда вопросы по WordPress требуют включения в них кода, который вызывает проблему. Вам вряд ли смогут помочь, если вы не знаете, какой участок кода отвечает за проблему на сайте.

**Конкретизируйте источник проблемы**

Это важно не только для вопроса, но и для вашего понимания происходящего на сайте. Прежде чем задавать вопрос, сделайте следующее:

- Сбросьте кеш браузера
- Отключите все плагины на сайте, кроме тех, которые напрямую завязаны на проблему (например, WooCommerce)
- Смените тему на стандартную, например, twentyseventeen
- Убедитесь, что проблема все еще существует, а не вызвана конфликтом плагинов/тем
- Если вопрос сводится к тому, что у вас проблема конфликта плагина A с плагином B, внесите эту информацию в вопрос
- В любом случае совершенно необходимо включить в вопрос информацию об активной теме, установленных плагинах, их версиях и версии WordPress
- Зачастую темы и плагины имеют схожие названия. Во избежание недоразумений, лучше приводить ссылку на тему/плагин в репозитории WordPress

**Платные темы или плагины**

Если проблема связана с платными темами или плагинами, будьте готовы к тому, что вероятность ответа на ваш вопрос резко понижается. Вряд ли стоит надеяться, что кто-то уже покупал это программное обеспечение и имеет опыт работы с ним. Как вариант, будьте готовы передать это ПО участнику сообщества, или предоставить доступ на ваш рабочий или тестовый сайт.

**Включите код в тело вопроса**

Проблема с WordPress в том, что код нельзя включить в сниппет на StackOverflow, и даже php песочницы типа http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ бесполезны. Код WordPress завязан на ядро системы, установленную тему и плагины. Приходится код включать в вопрос текстом. [Отформатируйте код](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) согласно стандартам сообщества.

Для того, чтобы понять, какой код отвечает за вывод того или иного элемента, посмотрите на готовую страницу в браузере, найдите более или менее уникальные стили, идентификаторы, теги html (например, `<article>`). Потом проведите поиск по файлам сайта. В phpStorm отлично работает Ctrl+Shift+F - поиск в проекте (или в папке плагина, или темы).

Обязательно включите в вопрос **сведения о местоположении кода** - `functions.php`, другой файл темы, файл плагина. Если код должен срабатывать по событию в WordPress, укажите это событие. Если код предназначен для административной части сайта, или должен выполняться о время вызова ajax, укажите это в вопросе. Ответ может очень сильно зависеть от этих сведений.

**Опишите структуру данных**

Код не висит в воздухе, он оперирует некими данными. Опишите, что это за данные. Приведите пример данных, которыми оперирует код.

**Посмотрите на свой вопрос со стороны**

Представьте, что это не ваш вопрос, и вы ничего не знаете ни о сайте, ни о сервере, ни о проблеме. Попробуйте взглянуть на вопрос чужими глазами и понять - какую еще информацию надо включить в него, чтобы он выглядел как [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Как отвечающий может смоделировать вашу проблему на своем тестовом сайте?

**Включите детальную информацию об ошибках**

Слова "не работает", "не выводит" не дают никакой информации о проблеме. Скорее всего, вопрос с такими постулатами будет просто проигнорирован. Покажите, какие ошибки на странице, в логах, в консоли браузера.

**Опишите желаемое поведение**

Если код работает, но не так, как хотелось бы, опишите желаемое поведение и его отличие от того, что вы наблюдаете. Только вы знаете, чего вы хотите.

**Стоит ли давать ссылку на сайт**

Такая практика совсем не приветствуется на StackOverflow, потому что при изменении вашего сайта, ценность вопроса станет равна нулю. Однако считаю, что в случае с WordPress иногда можно дать ссылку на реальный сайт, потому что зачастую смоделировать ситуацию на тестовом сайте WordPress бывает затруднительно, в силу причин, указанных выше. Тем не менее, такая ссылка никак не должна быть основным посылом вопроса, а служить лишь дополнением к тому коду, который приведен прямо в теле вопроса. Наличие ссылки иногда позволяет сэкономить время на ответ. В то же время, связка вопрос-ответ должна в конечном итоге давать полную информацию о проблеме и пути ее решения, с тем, чтобы любой посетитель сайта смог использовать эту информацию для решения своей такой же или похожей проблемы.

**Примите ответ**

Если ответ оказался полезным, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос. StackOverflow - это база знаний, внесите свой вклад в нее!

Comment: >"Практически всегда вопросы по WordPress требуют включения в них кода."  

С этим не согласен. Большинство вопросов не требуют кода, но многие требуют ссылки на сайт. Отсюда наблюдается некое противоречие с правилами SO. Тогда  либо удалять вопросы не требующие кода либо.. Надо что-от менять. Второй момент этого аспекта - на многие вопросы ответом будет использование готовых плагинов.

Comment: Еще момент - иногда задаются вопросы, требующие постепенных выяснения - сделай то, опиши результат. По результата-след шаг. и тд. Такие вопросы вообще не удобно решать на SO.

Comment: А воще ты написал много - столько никто читать не будет :) Если бы они могли читать - им бы это чтиво просто не понадобилось :)

Comment: @SeVlad Видишь ли, я писал это по предложению одного из админов SO - помнишь чат на троих? И в качестве примера мне был дан аналогичный вопрос - ответ про SQL. Там ещё подробнее и длиннее) Тем не менее, на тот вопрос на Мете регулярно ссылаются как на инструкцию.

Comment: Да помню, конечно. Но... Ты же видишь - подавляющее большинство вопросов по ВП не столько по кодингу, сколько по использованию ВП - найти решение для функционала или же разобраться "почему не работает". А таких, чтобы вкусные велосипеды  кто-то искал - таких вот мало. Катастрофически мало :(